# How do i block page from production but show in development in nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I tried to do this with `.nuxtignore` because with it you can ignore files "[during the build phase](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-ignore/)". But then I realized the page was no longer visible in development either.

I'm making a reference page (more involved than a .md) for developers to use with the project while doing component development. But i don't want end users to ever see the page when in production. How do I block the page from production but show in development in Nuxt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot ignore by configuration, but with a script by detecting if you are in dev mode and else redirect to another page, as below:

eg. `pages/test.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>Dev Only</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  asyncData({ isDev, redirect }) {
    if (!isDev) {
      redirect({ name: 'index' })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Context options for asyncData documentation https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ignore` property in `nuxt.config.js` to ignore files (or pages). Also use `env variable` to judge weather it is in production mode or development mode.

- ### Nuxt2

To use env variable in nuxt2, you can install `cross-env` package, and add some configs in `package.json` file. Also remember to create `.env` file for different environment first. The example codes are as follow:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

  export default {
     // ...
     ignore: [
        process.env.ENVIROMENT === 'production' ? 'pages/debug/*' : '',
        process.env.ENVIROMENT === 'production' ? 'pages/someOtherPage.vue' : '',
     ],
  }
```

```
// .env.local

  ENVIROMENT = local
```

```
// .env.prod

  ENVIROMENT = production
```

```
// package.json

  {
    // ...
    "scripts": {
      "local": "cross-env ENV=local nuxt",
      "generate:prod": "cross-env ENV=prod nuxt generate"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "corss-env": "7.0.3"
    }
    // ...
  }
```

- ### Nuxt3

In nuxt3 `dotenv` is a build-in package, you just need to add some configs. Remember to add `VITE` prefix in you `.env.xxx` file. Sample codes are as follow:

```js
// nuxt.config.ts

  export default defineNuxtConfig({
    // ...
    ignore: [
        process.env.VITE_ENVIROMENT == "production" ? 'pages/poc/carousel.vue' : ''
    ]
  })
```

```
// .env.local

  VITE_ENVIROMENT = local
```

```
// .env.prod

  VITE_ENVIROMENT = production
```

```json
// package.json

  {
    // ...
    "scripts": {
      "local": "nuxt dev --dotenv .env.local",
      "generate:prod": "nuxt generate --dotenv .env.prod"
    }
    // ...
  }
```